# How can I iterate through possible completions in gnu readline?

Tags: autocomplete, gnu, readline

In a shell that implements [GNU Readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), I can click the  key to get a list of possible completions to what I started typing. For example:

```
C:\>cd P<TAB>
PerfLogs\             Program Files (x86)\  Python27\
Program Files\        ProgramData\
```

How can I now choose which completion I wish to use?

I know that If I want "Program Files" in the above example, I can type in "rogram Files", but I'm lazy :).

Isn't there some way for me to hit a keyboard shortcut that will iterate through the possible completions so I can quickly choose one? Something similar to auto-completion / intellisense in modern IDEs?

*Edit:* Might my solution be to use GNU Readline's `menu-complete` command (described below)? But how do I bind it to a key combination?

```
menu-complete ()

    Similar to complete, but replaces the word to be completed with a single match
from the list of possible completions. Repeated execution of menu-complete steps 
through the list of possible completions, inserting each match in turn. At the end of 
the list of completions, the bell is rung (subject to the setting of bell-style) and 
the original text is restored. An argument of n moves n positions forward in the list 
of matches; a negative argument may be used to move backward through the list. This 
command is intended to be bound to TAB, but is unbound by default.
```

Comment: You could just continue by typing `r` `Tab` (which will complete to `Program`) and then `\ ` `Tab` to get to `Program Files`. The `\ ` might be annoying to represent a single space, which is related to the convention to avoid spaces in file names in general. In this case it would in total be six keystrokes to reach `Program Files`: `Pr` `Tab` `\ ` `Tab`. I'm testing this in Bash; you are obviously on a Windows system, though, but I would guess it works in the same way there. I don't know how to enable "intellisense" like completion.

Comment: @DanielAndersson Windows tab-complete works differently; each `Tab` gives you a different option, unlike bash, which requires you to input another character to narrow it down

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a shell that uses `readline`, you need to bind [`menu-complete`](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#IDX142) to a key. It is not bound by default, `complete` is.

To do this, edit `~/.inputrc` and add the following:

```
TAB: menu-complete
```

This will probably affect all programs that use `readline`. Use the following to only have this apply to `bash`:

```
$if Bash
   TAB: menu-complete
$endif
```

Comment: Many thanks! Any idea what do I do if I'm on Windows, using clink? :) http://code.google.com/p/clink/

Comment: @urig It should use the path in the `INPUTRC` environment variable, or the file `_inputrc` in your home directory. See `rl_read_init_file` in `readline/readline/bind.c`

Comment: Found it! For clink, the inputrc file is somwhere like: C:\Program Files (x86)\clink\0.3.1\clink_inputrc_base

Comment: @urig True -- just wanted to add that. This is what `clink` sets the `INPUTRC` environment variable to in `clink/clink/dll/rl_env.c`. It even appears to ignore any predefined `INPUTRC` as well, always overriding it.

Comment: You should not modify `clink_inputrc_base` as it will be overwritten when you upgrade `clink`. That file contains the following lines: `$include ~/clink_inputrc`, `$include ~/_inputrc`, `$include ~/.inputrc`, so you may rather use any of those files in your `HOME` directory.

Answer (score 1):

[Command-line completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion) works in two different ways, depending on platform.

### Windows (NT and later)

First of all, the Windows command processor (cmd.exe) does *not* implement GNU Readline. Despite this, it does support tab-completion.

Specifically, cmd.exe utilizes "rotating completion", where each <kbd>Tab</kbd> presents a different option.

In your example, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> would first give you `PerfLogs`, then `Program Files`, etc.

### bash (and other Unix shells)

Most Unix shells utilize "prompting completion", where, as Daniel said above, you have to input another character to narrow the completion down.

See [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion#Completion_in_different_command_line_interfaces) of the linked-above Wikipedia article for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know how Windows handled this. Haven't used the command-line in that context extensively since the actual MS-DOS days.

Comment: Actually, Windows command line iterates through completion options - This is where I've gotten used to this functionality :)

Answer (score 0):

Specifically regarding this part of the question

> Isn't there some way for me to hit a keyboard shortcut that will iterate through the possible completions so I can quickly choose one? Something similar to auto-completion / intellisense in modern IDEs?

I'd say [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) is what you might want to investigate. Its a pretty fast fuzzy find and selection tool.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Please try to contain most relevant information from the link in your post. Read more about it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted).